# How can I troubleshoot 'call revert exception' error when using getTickets() method in Ethereum Smart Contract on Next.js?

Tags: next.js, ethereum, solidity

I get an error when I do getTickets but it was working on test

error

```
Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getTickets()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
```

page.js

```js
"use client"

import { ethers } from "ethers"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import Manager from "../artifacts/contracts/Manager.sol/Manager.json"

export default function Home() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [account, setAccount] = useState("");
  const [contract, setContract] = useState(null);
  const [tickets, setTickets] = useState([]);

  const getTickets = async () => {
    let res = await contract.getTickets();
    console.log(res);
    
    setTickets(res);
  }
  

  const initConnection = async () => {
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
      const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_requestAccounts",
      });
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      
      const newSigner = provider.getSigner();
      setAccount(accounts[0]);
      setContract(
        new ethers.Contract(
          "0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8",
          Manager.abi,
          newSigner
        )
      );
    }
    else {
      console.log("install metamask");
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    initConnection();
  }, []);

  return (
     <div>s
    </div>
  )
}
```

contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Manager {
    struct Ticket {
        uint8 status;
        string name;
    }

    Ticket[] public tickets;

    function createTicket(string memory _name) external {
        tickets.push(Ticket(0,_name));
    }

    function updateTicketName(uint _index, string memory _name) external{
        tickets[_index].name = _name;
    }

    function updateTicketStatus(uint _index, uint8 _status) external {
        tickets[_index].status = _status;
        
    }

    function getTickets() external view returns(Ticket[] memory){
        return tickets;
    }
}
```

I did tests on hardhat, it worked, but it should work on the product as well.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).